# How to pack my own code which uses openCV to a .deb?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, deb

I posted this same question on askubuntu. But people refused to answer and asked me to ask my question here.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and wrote two pieces of code. One which is in C++ and the other which is in Python. Below you will find everything which is related to my C++ code.

I would like to know how I can pack each code in a .deb so that the other person doesn't have any issues related to dynamic linking and doesn't have to install openCV on its machine.

So far I tried to simply create a folder which has the following structure:

```
~/Desktop/myTestDEB$ tree
.
├── DEBIAN
│   └── control
└── usr
    └── bin
        ├── main
        └── part1.png

3 directories, 3 files
```

Where main is the executable which I already compiled and afterwards copied to this folder.
Which I then packed this folder to a .deb package using: `sudo dpkg-deb --build myTestDEB/`

But when the other person installs my .deb on his laptop he gets this error:

`main: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_highgui.so.3.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Which is a dynamic linking error. I would have thought that packaging everythinginto a .deb file would solve anything related to dynamic linking.

What should I do to solve this issue? What if I want to do the same for Python code?

Comment: A deb file AFAIK does not resolve dependencies, unless you have a repo and configure it correctly. So you have to install the libraries needed.

Comment: The file itself does not *resolve* the dependencies, but a properly built package must declare them, so apt does the resolution. The problem here is @traducerad does not build his package properly, he bypasses debian infrastructure to create a defective package.

Comment: Follow the [debian packaging guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/first.en.html) and build a proper package. All those issues are tricky to get right, and package maintenance tools handle all of it automatically.